# How to validate form by getting exact value on integer field

Tags: python, django

I am new in Django, I am trying to validate a form to get the particular value, if value is not exact validate error. For example, i have a field in a model (cot_code), the field has a integer value (12345). I have created a form for this field, i want if the user enter 12345 in form, the form will be valid as success "code is correct", but when user enter a wrong code (55777) the form will raise a validator error "Wrong code". I do not know how to go on with the views.

Model:

```
class CotCode(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cot_code = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=True) # I have set this field as 12345 in model.
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'CotCode'
        verbose_name_plural = 'CotCode'
        ordering = ['-date']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Forms:

```
class CotCodeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CotCode
        fields = ('cot_code',)
```

Views:

```
@login_required
def TransferCOTView(request):
    #Don't know how to go on here
    return render(request, 'transfer_cotcode.html')
```

Template:

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="text-center needs-validation" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">C.O.T</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" placeholder="Enter your COT Code" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
           Please enter your C.O.T code.
        </div>
      </div>

       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm wave-effect my-2" value="{% trans 'Enter' %}"  style="box-shadow:none;font-weight:500;"/>

    </form>
```

Comment: Please do go through the official doc, [Django Form and Field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/)

Comment: @Arakkal...thanks. I have gone through the doc, I was able to create forms. But the problem is that, I could not get the exact value of integer field. I have manually saved the value of cot_code in model to be (12345). I have created a form form CotCode Model. Now how can I make form validate success when user enter 12345 in form input? And make form invalid when user enter a wrong value like 55788? Please help by coding.